# The import com.mockobjects.sql cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

import com.mockobjects.sql.*;

The above line creates the error The import com.mockobjects.sql cannot be resolved

Can anyone please tell me what I have to download to make it work? Wihch library to add to the build path? Its driving me nuts!

edit: I've already added the mockobject jar to my class build path.

Comment: I would suggest to download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mockobjects/mockobjects/0.1/mockobjects-0.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `com.mockobjects.sql` is the package of the [Mock Objects](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mockobjects/) . You can download the latest version which is released about 9 years ago from the [official website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mockobjects/files/mockobjects-java/0.09/) and [import the downloaded jars to your project build path.](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps004g/fall05/assign/final/addlibrary.html)

Comment: Add `mockobjects-jdk1.4-0.09.jar`?

Comment: Do I have to download that? I am on a windows system right now...I'll try. NVM, I can't find a site to downloaded from.

Comment: I just downloaded `mockobjects-bin-0.09.tar` in window platform and find that `com.mockobjects.sql`package is  inside the `mockobjects-jdk1.3-0.09.jar` and `mockobjects-jdk1.4-j2ee1.3-0.09.jar` . Most probably , you should also import `mockobjects-core-0.09.jar` too

Comment: I see, I downloaded mockobjects-bin-0.09.tar...But where do I go to download mockobjects-core-0.09.jar, I only find asian sites I can't understand.

Comment: I downloaded mockobjects-jdk1.4-0.09.jar and it worked, thanks!